# Tells me .themes folder already exists

Tags: themes, home-directory, hidden-files

I cant find the themes folder

so i tried to create one in the home directory but it tells me it already exists

Comment: And the system-wide *themes* folder is */usr/share/themes*.

Comment: Thanks you 2! @PRATAP  Thank you